# moved an excel file between two computers and curly brackets was added to formulas

Tags: arrays, excel, formula, brackets

Moved a file from my laptop to desktop. Laptop has Office 2021, Desktop has 2019.

Formulas like this:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(Earning!$A$1:$N$1000,MATCH(CONCATENATE(ROW()-ROW(G$2),"_",VALUE(E$1)),Earning!$N$1:$N$1000,0),COLUMN(Earning!$B$1)),"")
```

Now look like this:

```
{=IFNA(INDEX(Earning!$A$1:$N$1000,MATCH(CONCATENATE(ROW()-ROW(G$2),"_",VALUE(E$1)),Earning!$N$1:$N$1000,0),COLUMN(Earning!$B$1)),"")}
```

I know its something with arrays and I don't understand it completely. The file seems to work fine on both versions but I'm afraid to meet some errors in the future because I plan to work on the same excel files on both of these computers.

I read that these brackets appear if you ctrl + shift + enter them , which I didn't. I drag the formulas down.

Comment: 2021 Excel automaticly generates dynamic array while previous versions not.

Comment: Functionality-wise it shouldn't matter but it'll be easier for you working on your laptop so you don't need to use ctrl+shift+enter for array formulas.

Comment: @Black cat , If I work on this file on 2019, will it work the same on 2021?

Comment: See @Notus comment